# Split rdd and Select elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to capture a stream, transform the data, and then save it locally.

So far, streaming, and writing works fine. However, the transformation only works halfway.
The stream I receive consists out of 9 columns separated by "|". So I want to split it, and let's say select column 1,3, and 5. What I have tried looks like this, but nothing really let to a result

```
val indices =  List(1,3,5)        
linesFilter.window(Seconds(EVENT_PERIOD_SECONDS*WRITE_EVERY_N_SECONDS), Seconds(EVENT_PERIOD_SECONDS*WRITE_EVERY_N_SECONDS)).foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
            if (rdd.count() > 0) {
          rdd
          .map(_.split("\\|").slice(1,2))
            //.map(arr => (arr(0), arr(2)))) 
            //filter(x=> indices.contains(_(x)))) //selec(indices)
            //.zipWithIndex
           .coalesce(1,true)

//the replacement is is used so that I get a csv file at the end
            //.map(_.replace(DELIMITER_STREAM, DELIMITER_OUTPUT))
            //.map{_.mkString(DELIMITER_OUTPUT) }
            .saveAsTextFile(CHECKPOINT_DIR + "/output/o_" + sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
}
```

Has anyone a tip how do I split a rdd and then only grab specific elements out of it?

Edit Input:

```
val lines = streamingContext.socketTextStream(HOST, PORT)
val linesFilter = lines
          .map(_.toLowerCase)
          .filter(_.split(DELIMITER_STREAM).length == 9)
```

Input stream is that:

```
536365|71053|white metal lantern|6|01-12-10 8:26|3,39|17850|united kingdom|2017-11-17 14:52:22
```

Comment: Provide your input details, which you are converting into rdd.

Comment: `rdd.map{line => val words = line.split("\\|") 
      (words(0),words(2),words(4)) }` you don't need to rdd.count. And are you sure that the stream contains fixed words separated by "|" or else you will get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone.

As you recommended, I modified my code like that:

```
private val DELIMITER_STREAM = "\\|"

val linesFilter = lines
          .map(_.toLowerCase)
          .filter(_.split(DELIMITER_STREAM).length == 9)
          .map(x =>{
            val y = x.split(DELIMITER_STREAM)
            (y(0),y(1),y(3),y(4),y(5),y(6),y(7))})
```

and then in the RDD

```
if (rdd.count() > 0) {

  rdd
    .map(_.productIterator.mkString(DELIMITER_OUTPUT))
    .coalesce(1,true)
    .saveAsTextFile(CHECKPOINT_DIR + "/output/o_" + sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))

  }
```